# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine - while starting the mule-enterprise-3.6.0\bin\mule.bat

Tags: java, mule

I downloaded mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.6.0

when im trying to starting the mule.bat which in the following location

```
mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.6.0\mule-enterprise-3.6.0\bin\mule.bat
```

it's giving the following error :

```
Launching a JVM...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
JVM exited while loading the application.
```

Can any one provide me help..

Comment: not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that the JVM couldn't reserve memory for it to run. You will need to set the heap size to a smaller value, or clear more memory on your computer for it to run.

Edit the batch script, and look for the line(s) that run java. (If you need help with this, paste the script here)

In the lines that run java add something like this: `-Xmx64M`, after `java`. This will set the heap size to 64MB. You can change it around to see what works.

Comment: In AnyPointStudio.ini file just i have modified -Xmx1024m to -Xmx512m. I could able to open AnypointStudio. Thanks,